# Proof of monotonicity of $x^3+6x^2+12x+10$

Tags: functions

I want to proof that the function
$$f(x)=x^3+6x^2+12x+10$$
is a monotonic increasing function.

But the term $x^2$ confuses me because the inequality changes if $x\ge0$ or if $x\le0$. (I don't know derivatives)

Comment: Do you know about derivatives?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: If $a>0$ we have $f(x+a)-f(x)=a(a^2 + 3ax + 6a + 3x^2 + 12x + 12)$. The polynomial inside the parenthesis has discriminant $-3a^2<0$ and positive leading term $3x^2$. Therefore it is always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function can be written as $f(x)=(x+2)^3+2$ and with a translation it becomes $g(X)=X^3$ which is monotonic increasing for any $X\in\mathbb{R}$

Indeed if $a<b$ it follows that $a^3<b^3$ because $a^3-b^3<0\to (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and as $a^2+ab+b^2>0$ for any real $a,b$ so $a^3-b^3$ has the same sign as $a-b$, which proves that the function is strictly increasing on all $\mathbb{R}$

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

note that $$f'(x)=3x^2+12x+12=3(x+2)^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x < y$, both $\ge 0$ or $\le 0$. We shall show $f(x) \le f(y)$.

\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x) &= y^3-x^3 + 6(y^2-x^2)+12(y-x)\\
&= (y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)+6(y+x)(y-x)+12(y-x)\\
&= (y-x)(\underbrace{y^2+x^2}_{\ge 2xy}+xy+6x+6y+12)\\
&\ge (y-x)(3xy+6x+6y+12)\\
&= 3(y-x)(xy+2x+2y+4)\\
&= 3(y-x)(x+2)(y+2)\\
&\ge 3\underbrace{(y-x)}_{>0}(x+2)^2\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}

Therefore, $f$ is monotonically increasing on $\langle -\infty, 0]$ and $[0, +\infty\rangle$.

Monotonicity on $\mathbb{R}$ follows from the fact that for $x < 0$ we have:

$$f(x) = x\underbrace{(x^2+6x + 12)}_{\ge 0} + 10 < 10 = f(0)$$

and for $x > 0$ we have:

$$f(x) = x\underbrace{(x^2+6x + 12)}_{\ge 0} + 10 > 10 = f(0)$$

Comment: Is it correct to substitute y^2 + x^2 with 2xy? Equality shouldn't hold anymore after that substitution.

Also where does the final (x+2)^2 come from?

Nevermind the above, just saw the edits! ;)

Comment: @ANVerona No, but inequality holds because of AM-GM:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \ge \sqrt{x^2y^2} = xy$$

Comment: page didn't refresh! I saw corrections, thx

Comment: On the other hand, now i noticed it should be $|xy|$, so the above works only for $x$ and $y$ of the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is
$3x^2+12x+12=3(x^2+4x+4)
=3(x+2)^2
\ge 0$.